# validating multi-layers nested objects in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, class-validator

Im trying to use classValidator decorators in nestJs to validate incomming request of the following type

```
{
    address: string
    location: { 
        longitude: string, 
        latitude : string
    }
}
```

. the problem is that its just limited to one layer of nestedObject . the one below works

```
class ProjectLocation { 
    @IsString()
    address: string; 
}

export class CreateProjectDto {

    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(()=>ProjectLocation)
    location:ProjectLocation
}
```

but when another nested layer is added to ProjectLocation it doesn't work and also you can't use @ValidatedNested inside ProjectLocation to add another class Type to it .

> Error : No overload matches this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as expected for me, consider the following:

```
class SomeNestedObject {
    @IsString()
    someProp: string;
}

class ProjectLocation {
    @IsString()
    longitude: string;
    @IsString()
    latitude: string;
    @ValidateNested()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Type(() => SomeNestedObject)
    someNestedObject: SomeNestedObject;
}

export class CreateProjectDto {
    @IsString()
    address: string;
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(() => ProjectLocation)
    location: ProjectLocation;
}
```

Note that I'm using `IsNotEmpty` on `someNestedObject` to handle the case if the prop is missing.

---

Here's two examples of invalid requests that are validated correctly:

Example 1:

```
Request-Body:    
    {
        "address": "abc",
        "location": { 
            "longitude": "123",
            "latitude" : "456",
            "someNestedObject": {}
        }
    }

Response:
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "location.someNestedObject.someProp should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

Example 2:

```
Request-Body:
{
    "address": "abc",
    "location": { 
        "longitude": "123",
        "latitude" : "456"
    }
}
Response:
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "location.someNestedObject should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: thank you works for me as well. seems like we should explicitly ask it to validate something on nested object key to make it  validate inner types .

Comment: this does not work in case of arrays how do we handle that